# Formulation and solution of a minimization problem that consists of a binary variable multiplied by a convex function.

Tags: convex-optimization, integer-programming, binary-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have the following optimization problem which can be solved using convex optimization toolbox after some relaxations:$${\mathcal{P1}}:{\rm{     }}\mathop {\min }\limits_{\left\{ \mathbf{A}_{i} \right\}_{i = 1}^L,\left\{ \mathbf{B}_{i} \right\}_{i = 1}^L}  \sum\limits_{i = 1}^L rank(\mathbf{C}_{i})$$
$$s.t\;\;\;rank(\mathbf{D}_{i})=d$$where $L$ is the number of users and  $\mathbf{C}_{i}$ and $\mathbf{D}_{i}$ are functions of ${\left\{ \mathbf{A}_{i} \right\}_{i = 1}^L,\left\{ \mathbf{B}_{i} \right\}_{i = 1}^L}$. Now if the number of users is $N$ instead of $L$ and only $L$ users can participate in the system, so I want to select the optimum set of $L$ users out of $N$ that minimizes the objective function. I formulated the new problem as the following by adding a binary variable: $${\mathcal{P2}}:{\rm{     }}\mathop {\min }\limits_{\left\{ \mathbf{A}_{i} \right\}_{i = 1}^L,\left\{ \mathbf{B}_{i} \right\}_{i = 1}^L,\left\{ \mathbf{S}_{i} \right\}_{i = 1}^N}  \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N S_irank(\mathbf{C}_{i})$$
$$s.t\;\;\;rank(\mathbf{D}_{i})=d$$
$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^NS_i=L$$
$$S_i\in\left\{0,1\right\}$$Is the formulation of $\mathcal{P2}$ correct? If so, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The link to convex optimization here is extremely tenuous. How can even the first one be "solved" using convex optimization? It's not convex, and relaxations do not reliably solve the original problem. And then your modification takes things even further away from convexity.

Comment: It's indeed not convex in its direct form but by using nuclear norm as a convex envelope for the objective function and by relaxations of the the constraints to be convex constraints, P1 will be convex in A_i alone or B_i alone. So using alternating minimization technique it can be solved using cvx toolbox.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "solved". There is no guarantee that you'll hit the global optimum with that approach. And again, you're now making things significantly more complex, because now it's not even convex in $A$ or $B$.

Comment: Yes of course you're completely right there is no guarantee that this approach hits the global optimum. I just want to know is the formulation of P2 true? In other words, to select a subset of users out of a larger set, can I add this binary variable in the optimization problem? Also, to what extend is the new problem hard to be solved?